# Clarification of Hurwitz's Theorem in C

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, analytic-functions

Hurwitz's theorem:

"Let $\{ f_n\}$ be a sequence of analytic functions on an open set $D$, which converges uniformly to a function $f$ on compact subsets of $D$. If the functions $f_n$ are nowhere zero, then $f$ is either identically zero or nowhere zero".

The following proof by contradiction is taken from my textbook (modified a little):

Suppose $f (z) = 0$ for some $z ∈ D$ and that $f(z) \not \equiv 0$. Take a small curve $\gamma \subset D $, centered at $z$, then $f(z) \neq 0$ on $\gamma$. Thus,
$$
\frac{f'_n}{f_n} \to \frac{f'}{f} \text{ on } \gamma
$$
and therefore,
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f_n'(z)}{f_n(z)}dz=0 \tag{*}
$$
However,
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz \geq 1
$$
according to the argument principle. Thus, we have a contradiction and therefore $f(z) \equiv 0$ or nowhere zero.

**My question is**:

In (*), why is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f_n'(z)}{f_n(z)}dz=0$? Based on my understanding, if $f_n \to f$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f_n'(z)}{f_n(z)}dz \text{ shoud}=1$ instead.

Comment: The theorem is obviously false unless you assume that $D$ is connected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each function $f_n$ is nowhere $0$, and therefore, by the argument principle$$\oint\frac{f_n'(z)}{f_n(z)}\,\mathrm dz=0.$$So$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\oint\frac{f_n'(z)}{f_n(z)}\,\mathrm dz=0$$

Comment: sorry i have two questions: 1) why is the contour integral=0 since each $f_n$ is nowhere 0? 2)for the above proof, why is $$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz \geq 1
$$? (I know there is at least 1 zero but do not know the number of poles)

Comment: 1) The argument principle says that that integral is $2\pi i$ times the number of zeros minus the number of poles of $f_n$. So, since there are no zeros and there are no poles, that integral is $0$. 2) That expression is the number of zeros of $f$ minus the number of poles. Since there is at least one zero and there are no poles…